# ActiveRecord::Enum initialized with hash or array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

Let's say we have this simple model:

```rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  enum stage: {Idea: "idea", Done: "done", "On hold": "on hold", Cancelled: "cancelled"}
  enum status: [:draft, :published, :archived]
end
```

When we access the enums  from the model (`Project.stages`, `Project.statuses`) we get as result an processed (by ActiveRecord::Enum) response, both as a hash.

```bash
irb(main):001:0> Project.stages
=> {"Idea"=>"idea", "Done"=>"done", "On hold"=>"on hold", "Cancelled"=>"cancelled"}
irb(main):002:0> Project.statuses
=> {"draft"=>0, "published"=>1, "archived"=>2}
```

I'm struggling to know when an enum was declared as a Hash or as an Array having only the model and the enum name.

Any idea on how to get the initial hash or array from an enum?

Comment: Why do you need to know? What problem are you trying to solve by determining how an enum was defined? Would you want to treat `enum status: %i[draft published archived]` and `enum status: { draft: 0, published: 1, archived: 2 }` differently?

Comment: @muistooshort yes, I'm working on a feature for Avo (https://avohq.io/) where i need to treat them slight differently

Comment: if can't figure this out we'll need to ask the developer to specify the type of the enum and we are trying to avoid that

Comment: I don't think you can, the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8015c2c2cf5c8718449677570f372ceb01318a32/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L209) just checks how it can iterate over the values (`each_pair` if it is a Hash, `each_with_index` otherwise).

Comment: I wonder if somehow we can get that `values` argument that source receive

Comment: Maybe what you actually want here is just to use `Project.type_for_attribute('stages')` to get the type of the underlying database column?

Comment: On a side note - `enum stage: {Idea: "idea", Done: "done", "On hold": "on hold", Cancelled: "cancelled"}` is also very unidiomatic as using uppercase keys will result in methods with uppercase names like `Idea`, `Idea?` and `Idea!`. If you call `Idea` with an implicit reciever (without self) Ruby will think its a constant. Don't do this. Your enum keys should be lower case and snake case.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and for the advices @max, i totally agree with you. As i mentioned in the comments above, this question pop up while i was developing for Avo. We are committed to make Avo works for every developer even if the hosting app make good or bad use of enums . Anyway, `Project.type_for_attribute('stage')` gives the answer we was looking for!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should not be treating them differently due to the principle of least suprise.**

`enum status: [:draft, :published, :archived]` is just an implicit shorthand for defining an enum where the mapping is the same as the indices of the array. That's how its documented and having your code do something else opens up for a real WTF moment.

Defining enums implicitly is also regarded as a bad practice since adding new statuses in the middle of the array will break your application in a very sneaky way. There is even a Rubocop cop that detects the use of arrays by using a regular expression on the source code.

Its actually just a sloppy way of writing `enum status: { draft: 0, published: 1, archived: 2}`. You shouldn't be encouraging its use.

The arguments you pass to `enum` are just used to metaprogram the setters, getters and create the metadata which stores the enum mapping. It doesn't store the original arguments as there is no point to that.

If you REALLY wanted to do this you could monkeypatch the enum method:

```
module WonkyEnum
  # this is silly. Don't do this
  def enum(definitions)
    @_enum_definitions ||= []
    @_enum_definitions.push(definitions)
    super(definitions)
  end
end
```

But whatever the real problem is here there is most likely a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @max! We are building an select field where the developer can use an enum as options. We do not want to use them differently but after some debugging we found out that if we want the select to work perfectly we need to pre-process the options differently when the enum has an simple array or an hash declaration.


PS: After some investigation i noticed we weren't using `options_for_select()` on our select tag, that fixed some of our issues!